# What does "provides plenty to work on" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> For now, we note that programming a computer to pass a rigorously
> applied test provides plenty to work on.

Does "plenty to work on" here mean there is a lot of things to be done?

Comment: two word verb: to work on [something].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close, and would be correct in most usage.
`Plenty to work on` (in this case) does not mean that there are a lot of things to be done,
just that the single task mentioned ('programming a computer') will require lots of effort and/or thought.

Comment: "programming to pass a rigorously applied test" is the plenty to work on....